Можете помочь с деплоингом в Гитхаб
Сделал сайт на основе React, загрузил на репозиторий а, сделал:

npm build
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
за коммитил и push
npm run deploy

Было написано что успешно загружено, посмотрел вышел домен, зашел на сайт а там совсем другая страница

Посмотрел, старался понять и исправить но так и не смог задеплоид свой проект. Как залить проект?

Здесь есть довольно подробная инструкция, проверьте каждый шаг: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages
